# Differences in if condition

Tags: perl

I found this while exploring some working code. 
Also in perl coding I am still a newbie. Here is my question:
**What the differences between this IF condition**?

```
if ($command =~ /send|regd|succ|fail|recv/)
```

and this one

```
if ( ($command == "send") || ($command == "regd") || ($command == "succ")
     || ($command == "fail") || ($command == "recv"))
```

Comment: The second `if` statement is using the numerical equality operator `==` to test strings.  This should be `eq`, the string equality operator.

Comment: The first one will match too much - any string with send, regd, etc in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, as the commenter mentioned, == does a numeric comparison. if a string doesn't look like a number, its numeric value is 0, so it's likely that $command would appear to be equal to all of those strings if == is used. The correct way to compare strings is with eq, e.g., `if ($command eq "send")`.

Even with the correct equality operator, there's still a difference. The first version uses a pattern match and the pattern isn't anchored, so it can match anywhere in the string. For example, if `$command` is "blahblahsendxxxxxx", `$command =~ /send/` is true. You can anchor the pattern to make sure it matches the entire string by placing a ^ at the beginning and a $ at the end.

Comment: thank you for the answer and for simple explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Andy mentioned, you need to use `eq` and not `==`, and should anchor your regex. You also don't need to wrap every condition in your `||` chain in parenthesis in this case.

There are 2 'differences' I can think of: Performance and Readability. The '||' chain is more performant, but only slightly. If you added more terms, the regex would eventually beat it. The regex is probably more readable, and easier to extend and modify.

Here's the Benchmark I used to check performance.

```
use Benchmark 'cmpthese';

my $cmd = 'recv';

cmpthese( -1, {
    REG => sub {
        if ($cmd =~ /^(?:send|regd|succ|fail|recv)$/) {
            return 1;
        }   
    },  
    OR  => sub {
        if ($cmd eq 'send'||$cmd eq 'regd'||$cmd eq 'succ'||$cmd eq 'fail'||$cmd eq 'recv') {
            return 1;
        }   
    },  
});
```

I'm checking for `recv` as it's the last in the chain should be the slowest to pass.

However, if it's performance your after, define a hash of the valid commands at the top of your script. Later, you can just check if the hash contains that command key. It's far and away the fastest method. It's also very readable, and trivially easy to extend with additional commands.

```
my %valid = map { $_ => 1 } qw( send regd succ fail recv );
# Later ...
if ( $valid{$cmd} ) { return 1; }
```

Comment: The comparisons get worse if the name provided doesn't match (so one of the words passed to the test is `cataclysm` or `tectonic` or something else).  Then it has to do more work each time to establish that it doesn't match, whereas the regex detects the mismatch very much more quickly.  A word such as `failure` or `success` would make the regex work a little more (it would have to process 4 characters instead of just 1), but it is still quicker as the number of alternatives increases.

Comment: @Joshua I'm appreciate for your answer between Performance and Readability. I will consider it when do a coding in a future. TQSM. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for first condition: The string "$command" matches any of the text/portion of the text with the value "send" or "regd" or "succ" or "fail" or "recv" irrespective of the position.

Explanation for second condition: The second code syntax should should have been 
    if ($command eq "send" || $command eq "regd" || $command eq "succ" || $command eq "fail" || $command eq "recv") instead of the one stated above. Unlike the first condition, in the second condition the string $command should exactly match the text "send" or "regd" or "succ" or "fail" or "recv"